# Using break in "ensure" block while doing exception handling in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement exception handling in Ruby while connecting to the databases. When the user enters incorrect DB information, I want my program to print an user friendly message on the screen and then give 2-more chances to the user to enter the correct values.

```
    begin
        conn=Java::Oracle.jdbc::OracleDriver.new.connect("#{url}", props)
        log.info "connection established!"
    rescue => e
        log.error "Connection failed - #{e}"

    ensure
                    puts "Please enter correct DB inputs"
        #break

    end
    puts ("Don't come here")
    puts("I came here")
```

I have 2-questions now:

1.How can I stop the controller by going to last "puts" statements if there a connection error? I tried to use "break" inside "ensure" block. I know that its not a good practice but at least it is helps in not printing "puts" statements. But using break prints the following error message at the end:
`org.jruby.exceptions.JumpException$BreakJump`

Output with break in ensure block:

```
  Please enter correct DB inputs
  org.jruby.exceptions.JumpException$BreakJump`
```

Output without break in ensure block:

```
   Please enter correct DB inputs
   Don't come here
   I came here
```

2.Where shall I ask the user to re-enter the correct values? Is it in the "rescue" block?

Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
def tryConnect
  result = false
  begin
    Java::Oracle.jdbc::OracleDriver.new.connect("#{url}", props)
      result = true
    rescue
  end
  result
end

while !tryConnect
  # try again
end
```

Or similar.

One routine to try, one to retry, use the results to drive the output. Try writing your tests first, this sort of thing is less likely to happen.